# No such file or directory: error when read excel file in flask

Tags: python, flask, openpyxl

I am working on a flask app, I am trying to read an excel file but I am getting errors.

this is the code for reading the excel file

```
@app.route('/getFile', methods=['POST'])
def getFile():
    file = request.files['file']
    pandas.read_excel(file, engine='openpyxl')
```

And this the error I get

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory:
 "<FileStorage: 'mock.xlsx' ('application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')>"
```

Any hint?

Comment: Please provide all the relevant code. What is `file`?

Comment: Looks like `file` is a pointer to a storage object that contains metadata as well as the file content itself. Without more information about what that storage object actually is it is not possible to come to a complete answer. The generic answer is you need to pull the actual file content out and pass that to `read_excel()`

Comment: @CharlieClark this is the   `file = request.files['file']`

Answer (score 0):

This solves my error. read the file with the `read()` method then with `read_excel()`

```
@app.route('/getFile', methods=['POST'])
def getFile():
    file = request.files['file']
    data = pd.read_excel(file.read())
```